# Check for installed Excel version, then load COM object library dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, excel, com, load, interop

I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to write data to an excel file in C#. I am using Excel 2010, so I have Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library added as reference.. But now I need to make the program work on Excel 2003 and above. So, I removed my reference to Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library and now looking for a way to check the installed Excel version on the machine then use it's COM object library.

Currently, I use this code for checking the version, but it returns "2007" instead of "2010".
What am I doing wrong?

```
 namespace OfficeVersionCheck
{
    using System;
    using Microsoft.Win32;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RegistryKey localMachine = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\");

            string version = string.Empty;

            foreach (string key in localMachine.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                if (key == "11.0")
                    version = "2003";
                else if (key == "12.0")
                    version = "2007";
                else if (key == "14.0")
                    version = "2010";

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(version))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            Console.Write(version);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Now after checking the version, I need to load its COM object library to use in my program. Is there a way to do this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just reference the "old" Excel 2007 PIA/Library? This will work on all subsequent versions of Excel.

Comment: I only have Excel 2010 installed on my machine but I need to make my program to work on Excel 2003 and 2007. So, I'm thinking of adding the library programatically based on the Excel version installed in a particular machine.

Comment: I understand but it's over complicated IMHO. Just grab an old Excel PIA (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18346), and you don't have to do all this.

Comment: I guess. But I'm required to do so.. I need help..

Comment: I tried to install O2003PIA.MSI, but it says that I have to install MS Excel 2003 first.. How can I reference this older Excel 2003 PIA/Library?

Comment: Yes, the setup is broken - too old :-), but just extract the content of the .MSI with any tool that supports it (like 7-zip) and reference the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll from there.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to make it wok on my machine.. But I'm still forced to dynamically load the dlls... I will try using 'Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(_dllPath);'

Comment: Is the path for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll similar for every version of Excel?

Comment: You shouldn't load the DLL dynamically, just ship it with your program, like any other referenced assembly, like if you had developed it yourself. The path isn't important. This DLL as is will work with all versions of Excel after 2003. It just contains definitions, not code.

Comment: Thanks. I extracted the files to a new folder on the desktop, added EXCELPIA.dll (version 11) as a reference, and set its Copy Local property to true.. Should this be enough to make it work on Excel 2003 and all the newer versions?

Comment: I think so yes but of course you should try it

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tested it on Excel 2007 and it works. It just shows something about conditional formatting not supported but everything seemed to be displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have both `12.0` and `14.0` keys in your registry.

For the second part of your question consider using the late binding. For more information about using late binding in C#, see [KB 302902: Binding for Office Automation Servers with Visual C# .NET.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302902)

Search for Late Binding produced another good article [here](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Using-Late-Bound-COM-Objects/).

Comment: Oh thanks! Now, I would like to ask if there is a way to load the COM object library for the particular version of Excel to use on my project, so I can write on an Excel file. How could I do this?

Comment: @jaqui Updated my answer for late binding suggestion.